# What is the solution of following command?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, gnome-terminal

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

I accidentally gave the above command in terminal that results in disabling of two finger scroll. Also cursor is not moving as it used to, something like lag. Please suggest some alternate to get out of it.

Comment: How about a reboot?

Answer (score 4):

You unloaded the kernel module `psmouse` and re-loaded it with a non-default parameter setting. Simply unload it again and re-load it with the default parameters:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```